# .htaccess Rewrite - traffic to a folder to resolve to one of it's subfolders without changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have traffic that currently resolves to a folder, to resolve to a subfolder within that folder without changing the URL.

There are solutions online for making a subfolder the website root, but not to make a subfolder resolve to one of it's own subfolders.

---

The solution is needed for a site that has a wild subdomain, but the site itself is an add-on domain which, from my understanding, is treated as a subdomain itself for some purposes.

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.net$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.net [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ myfolder/ [L]
```

Comment: You've tagged this with *.htaccess* and *mod-rewrite* ... it seems like you already know what the tools are so what have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I've tried a few different solutions and none of them seem to work.Here is one attempt.

Comment: RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.net$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.net [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ myfolder/ [L]

Comment: Could you please update the question ... it's a bit hard to read that in a comment :)

Comment: I think this will negate your first rewrite `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` as it **is** a directory within a directory you're trying to route to - so the *not directory* condition will fail...

Comment: Not clear what problem are you solving by this code. Can you clarify with examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to redirect all requests for the path `/foo` to resources that would otherwise have to be requested under `/foo/bar`.

```
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ /foo/bar/$1
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for other readers.